# Can this code be changed to support a preview in the print dialog?

Tags: visual-c++, printing, mfc, webbrowser-control

I am not sure if this is an issue that can be resolved with coding or is by design. I am running the latest version of Windows 11 with all updates. And my application is a MFC dialog application built with Visual Studio 2022.

My application uses a `CHtmlView` control and the user can trigger a **Print Preview**. This event will trigger the following code:

```
void CChristianLifeMinistryHtmlView::DoPrintPreview()
{
    ExecWB(OLECMDID_PRINTPREVIEW, OLECMDEXECOPT_PROMPTUSER, nullptr, nullptr);

    HWND HWND_PP = nullptr ;
    const auto t1 = ::GetTickCount64();
    auto t2 = ::GetTickCount64(); // Extra line required for 'while' rearrangement.
    while (HWND_PP == nullptr && t2 - t1 <= 6000) // if found or Timeout reached...
    {
        HWND HWND_FG = ::GetForegroundWindow(); // Get the ForeGroundWindow
        if (HWND_FG != nullptr)
        {
            TCHAR szClassName[256]{} ;

            ::GetClassName(HWND_FG, &szClassName[0], 256);
            if (lstrcmp(&szClassName[0], IE_PPREVIEWCLASS) == 0) // Check for Print Preview Dialog
                HWND_PP = HWND_FG ;
        }

        theApp.PumpMessage();
        t2 = ::GetTickCount64();
    }

    if (HWND_PP != nullptr)
    {
        RECT workArea{};

        ::SystemParametersInfo( SPI_GETWORKAREA, 0, &workArea, 0 );
        ::MoveWindow(HWND_PP, workArea.left, workArea.top,
            workArea.right - workArea.left, workArea.bottom - workArea.top, TRUE);
    }
}
```

This code works fine, and I get a good print preview, resized to the display. For example:

[image]

Now, if I hit Print from here it displays:

[image]

Opting to print to PDF looks the same:

[image]

Prior to the recent Windows 11 Updates these latter "print dialogs" looked different with no preview anyway. But since this updated version of the system "print dialog" can cope with a preview, is there no way to get our existing `CHtmlView` preview displayed there?

This is only a cosmetic thing because I have a standard preview for the user to see anyway (snap 1). But it would be the icing on the cake if that preview could someone be fed into this popup print window.

Is this something we can do by code or is it a "system / by design issue"?